# Is it possible to use Codable subclasses without explicitly decoding?

Tags: swift

I've used `struct MyThing:Codable { }` to parse JSON a few times. Now I'd like to use a `class` instead of `struct`, because `struct` isn't really suited for the kind of work I need done (mutability, conformance etc.), and some subclassing. I tried this:

```
class Beverage:Codable{
    var name:String = ""
}
class Beer:Beverage{
    var alcoholPercent:Double = 0
}
```

I don't necessarily receive a list of multiple different types of beverages in the same list, let's say I just want to decode a list of `[Beer]`. If I try this with a json with a single beer like `{"name": "Hansa", "alcoholPercent": 5.4}` and try to decode it to the Beer-class, like this:

```
let beer = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Beer.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

the `beer` will have `name: Hansa` and `alcoholPercent: 0.0`. The name is correct, but the alcoholPercent is the default value in the class.

Is there a magic way to make subclasses automatically conform to `Codable` without explicitly setting the key/value of every variable?

**This** is working:

```
class Beverage:Codable{
    var name:String = ""
}
class Beer:Beverage{
    var alcoholPercent:Double = 0

    enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey{
        case alcoholPercent
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.alcoholPercent = try! values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .alcoholPercent)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

With this code, I get `"Hansa"` and `5.4`.
Why do I have to explicitly conform to `Codable` for subclasses, but not for the base class for this to work? Is there a way to do this without all the manual code? I feel like this should've worked out-of-the-box without needing the required init.

Comment: `struct isn't really suited for this kind of work`. Not really true. You only have to architecture differently.

Comment: @Sulthan I was thinking of having a single class for both decoding from web **and** store it in CoreData, meaning that the class must conform to both `Codable` **and** `NSManagedObject` (which is a subclass of `NSObject`). I'm not sure if it's possible yet, but that's what I meant to try. If I want to conform to NSManagedObject **I can't use struct** (as far as I know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is compiler synthesis of an override of `init(from:)` in `Beer`. Swift doesn't do that. This has been discussed on the Swift forum, for example [in this thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-does-subclassing-a-codable-class-produce-class-has-no-initializers/23586). Itai Ferber is the primary Apple engineer responsible for the design and implementation of `Codable` so you can consider his response authoritative.

If you remove the `Codable` conformance from `Beverage` and add it to `Beer` directly (and to any other leaf subclasses of `Beverage`) then you might get the behavior you want. That will only work if you don't need the conformance on `Beverage` itself though.

Comment: Oh. Well that.. sucks. An interesting read, though! Sadly, I need multiple layers of subclassing, and the ability to instantiate almost all of them. I found some posts suggesting to keep the subclasses as their own codable classes, each of them retaining their own "superclass" as a variable (e.g Beer holds a `var beverage`, no inheritance, and walking backwards 20 years). I'll do some more digging to find out if there are other options for this particular scenario.